# US visa validity for Dual Citizen of Syria and Antigua

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, syrian-citizens, antigua

I presented myself to the US embassy for a B2 visa appointment as an Antigua and Barbuda citizen, but I also hold a Syrian passport. The visa processing officer ended up approving my application but decided to treat me as a Syrian citizen even though I specified Antigua and Barbuda nationality on my application. This means they granted me a single entry with a validity up to 3 months instead of the 10 years which normally an Antigua and Barbuda citizen would get. They also mentioned that the visa will be stamped on the Syrian passport instead of the Antiguan one. The officer mentioned that this is the US policy. However, I could not find any reference for such a policy when reading online. Do you think there is such a policy?

Comment: The [FAQ on the matter](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/visa-applicants-from-state-sponsors.html) does not appear to adequately address your question, but as the US considers Syria to be a "state sponsor of terrorism", Syrian nationals are indeed unfortunately at a serious disadvantage when applying for a US visa.

Comment: "They also mentioned that the visa will be stamped on the syrian passport and the antiguan one": really?  It's directly contrary to the State Department's visa policy to issue two visas of the same type concurrently, even in passports of different countries: https://fam.state.gov/search/viewer?format=html&query=dual&links=DUAL&url=/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_2_C

Comment: @phoog they didn't want to issue two visas. Only one visa but they decided to stick to on the syrian passport and not the antiguan which I presented in the app2

Comment: Did you ask them about the policy articulated in the Foreign Affairs Manual?

Comment: @phoog yes, they shared the following url for my reference https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/Visa-Reciprocity-and-Civil-Documents-by-Country/AntiguaandBarbuda.html

Answer (score -2):

For most cases of most countries, having a citizenship of a country grants you privileges. If you are a citizen of country A and country A citizens don't need a visa, then you don't need a visa, whether or not you are also a citizen of country B.

However with the US and Syrian citizenship it's different. Syrian citizens are subject to restrictions, and those restrictions apply whether or not you are also a citizen of another country. The visa processing officer treated you absolutely correctly and according to the law.

There isn't a law saying "treat Syrian citizens as if they weren't dual", it just says "Syrian citizens are subject to these restrictions..." and those restrictions apply regardless of other citizenships. You are a Syrian citizen, so the restrictions apply to you.

Comment: This answer disagrees with the policy published at https://fam.state.gov/search/viewer?format=html&query=reciprocity&links=RECIPROC&url=/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040308.html#M403_8_3_A

Comment: @phoog Yes, that is the general principle I talk about in the first paragraph. The regulation you quote only applies to reciprocity. But there are rules saying effectively "If you are a Syrian citizen then you are treated like this..." which are additive - they are subject to the those rules as well as the ones for the country whose passport the applicant presents.

Comment: Where are those rules?  They don't appear to be in the US code, the code of federal regulations, or the foreign affairs manual.

Comment: Here is an example:https://www.syria.law/index.php/restrictions-syrians-entering-united-states/ While the article deals primarily with the total ban on Syrian nationals, but also references the Visa Waiver Program Improvement and Terrorist Travel Prevention Act of 2015, which prohibited Syrian nationals from obtaining VWP entry even though they possessed other citizenships that qualified for it.

Comment: @phoog aren’t those regulations in one or more presidential executive orders? Some have been repealed but maybe some are still in force.

Comment: @DJClayworth the ban on using the VWP does not mean that dual citizens of Syria must use their Syrian passports to apply for US visas, nor does it mean that they must be processed according to the Syrian visa reciprocity schedule when applying for a visa with their other passport.

Comment: @jcaron there are various regulations in executive orders but none of those orders provides for the treatment described in this question.  In fact, the longest lasting executive order had an exception for "any dual national of a country designated under section 2 of this proclamation when the individual is traveling on a passport issued by a non-designated country."  But none of those executive orders are still in force.  The more I look for any rules as posited by this answer, the more convinced I am that they do not exist and that this answer is simply wrong.